# Is it okay if from within one stored procedure I call another one that sets a lower transaction isolation level?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, transaction-isolation

I have a bunch of utility procedures that just check for some conditions in the database and return a flag result. These procedures are run with READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level, equivalent to WITH NOLOCK.

I also have more complex procedures that are run with SERIALIZABLE isolation level. They also happen to have these same kind of checks in them.

So I decided to call these check procedures from within those complex procedures instead of replicating the check code.

Basically it looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckSomething]
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- Do checks

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoSomethingImportant]
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    EXECUTE [dbo].[CheckSomething]

    -- Do some work

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Would it be okay to do that? Will the temporarily activated lower isolation level somehow break the higher level protection or is everything perfect safe?

EDIT: The execution goes smoothly without any errors.

Answer (score 5):

It's [all here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) for SQL Server 2005. A snippet:

> When you change a transaction from one
>   isolation level to another, resources
>   that are read after the change are
>   protected according to the rules of
>   the new level. Resources that are read
>   before the change continue to be
>   protected according to the rules of
>   the previous level. For example, if a
>   transaction changed from READ
>   COMMITTED to SERIALIZABLE, the shared
>   locks acquired after the change are
>   now held until the end of the
>   transaction.
>
> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION
>   LEVEL in a stored procedure or
>   trigger, when the object returns
>   control the isolation level is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object
>   was invoked. For example, if you set
>   REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the
>   batch then calls a stored procedure
>   that sets the isolation level to
>   SERIALIZABLE, the isolation level
>   setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ
>   when the stored procedure returns
>   control to the batch.

In this example:

- Each isolation level is applied for the scope of the stored proc
- Resources locked by DoSomethingImportant stay under SERIALIZABLE
- Resources used by CheckSomething are READ UNCOMMITTED

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, when I did this in the past I was outside of a stored proc so the behavior was different